# Retrieving count of documents from firebase and adding a map asynchronously

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I'm developing and Android App with jetpack compose and I have a lazyColumn that its every row has items in it. I want to show item count for each row in my LazyColumn. I tried to write a counter function and it is almost working but not properly. It shows item count as null in starting app and when i clicked a row, go to other screen and turn back, then it is showing actual numbers.

Counter Function in ViewModel:

```
fun countOfAnalyze(currentPairId: String) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

        val newRef = database.collection("Pairs")
            .document(currentUserE)
            .collection("Pair")
            .document(currentPairId)
            .collection("Analysis")

        val documents= newRef.get().await()

        fun counter() : Int{
            var counter=0
            for (document in documents) {
                counter++
            }
            return counter
        }
                    val count= async {
                        counter()
                    }

                    pairCountMap[currentPairId] = count.await()

    }
```

CurrencyRow composable which is a row of LazyColumn :

```
@Composable
fun CurrencyRow(currency: PairListModel, navController: NavController, viewModel: ProfileViewModel) {

    viewModel.countOfAnalyze(currency.id!!) // ------> HERE CALL TO COUNTER FUNCTİON

    val currencyName= if (currency.currency!= null) { currency.currency!!.uppercase() } else { "" }
    
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .border(BorderStroke(2.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground), RoundedCornerShape(2.dp))
            .clickable {
                val encodedUrl = URLEncoder
                    .encode(currency.currency, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
                    .uppercase()
                navController.navigate("pair_detail_screen/${currency.id}/${encodedUrl}")
            }
    ) {
        Text(
            text = currencyName ,
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            fontWeight = ExtraBold,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .weight(3f)
        )

        Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(2f)) {
            Text(
                text = "Analizlerim : ${viewModel.pairCountMap[currency.id]}",// HERE SHOW 
                                                                //   THE NUMBERS OF ANALYSIS
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = "Başarı Oranı : "/*TODO*/,
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
            )
        }
    }
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp))
}
```

How can i show the numbers of analysis asynchronously ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you try to log the value of `Log.d("TAG", newRef.get().await().documents.size.toString())`, are you always getting the correct number?

Comment: I have 6 pairs. And they have 6 subcollection(Analysis) as it should be. And if i log it ı'm getting 6 different number for 6 subcollections

Comment: So are you always getting the correct number?

Comment: yes I ' m getting the correct numbers everytime